# Why is My Azure API returning 500 internal server error when it works in a local environment?

Tags: c#, azure, rest, post, webapi

So i have a bit of a situation here. I'm supposed to deliver a paper for tomorrow in which we were supposed to create a Web API that, after correctly running on a local environment, had to be published on Azure with the App Service behind it being the methods implemented on the ASP.NET Core Web Application project (Web API) created in Visual Studio where i developed its code. Problem is: my POST method to add an event called *AddEvento* doesn't work when it's implemented to my App Service. What can i do? Thank you.

Stack Trace:

```
Inbound
(1.564 ms)
api-inspector (1.347 ms)
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "https://isitp2-apim.azure-api.net/api/Evento/AddEvento/%7B%22id%22:0,%22data%22:%222021-01-20T00:00:00%22,%22dataEvento%22:%222021-01-20T00:00:00%22,%22titulo%22:%22titulo%22,%22descricao%22:%22descricao%22,%22id_utilizador%22:1%7D",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "no-cache, no-store"
            },
            {
                "name": "Connection",
                "value": "Keep-Alive"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Length",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept",
                "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                "value": "gzip,deflate,br"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Language",
                "value": "pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
            },
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "isitp2-apim.azure-api.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "Max-Forwards",
                "value": "9"
            },
            {
                "name": "Referer",
                "value": "https://apimanagement.hosting.portal.azure.net/"
            },
            {
                "name": "DNT",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                "value": "61da05a1bfbd4516bbdd72e87f38adce"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
                "value": "cross-site"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
                "value": "cors"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
                "value": "empty"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-For",
                "value": "5.249.23.184,13.91.254.72:1984"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL",
                "value": "/api/Evento/AddEvento/%7B%22id%22:0,%22data%22:%222021-01-20T00:00:00%22,%22dataEvento%22:%222021-01-20T00:00:00%22,%22titulo%22:%22titulo%22,%22descricao%22:%22descricao%22,%22id_utilizador%22:1%7D"
            },
            {
                "name": "CLIENT-IP",
                "value": "10.0.32.7:31617"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-ARR-LOG-ID",
                "value": "df8d9a69-47ed-40d4-8428-9ad283d90e16"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID",
                "value": "apimwebappkkpLOUafnze1jpKywpfWHk5GUI9ZrSWiynyTu0DQ"
            },
            {
                "name": "WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME",
                "value": "apimwebappkkplouafnze1jpkywpfwhk5gui9zrswiynytu0dq.azurewebsites.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Original-URL",
                "value": "/api/Evento/AddEvento/{\"id\":0,\"data\":\"2021-01-20T00:00:00\",\"dataEvento\":\"2021-01-20T00:00:00\",\"titulo\":\"titulo\",\"descricao\":\"descricao\",\"id_utilizador\":1}"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-ARR-SSL",
                "value": "2048|256|C=US,O=Microsoft Corporation,CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 02|C=US,S=WA,L=Redmond,O=Microsoft Corporation,CN=*.azure-api.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-Proto",
                "value": "https"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-AppService-Proto",
                "value": "https"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-TlsVersion",
                "value": "1.2"
            },
            {
                "name": "DISGUISED-HOST",
                "value": "isitp2-apim.azure-api.net"
            }
        ]
    }
}
api-inspector (0.018 ms)
{
    "configuration": {
        "api": {
            "from": "/",
            "to": {
                "scheme": "https",
                "host": "isitp2.azurewebsites.net",
                "port": 443,
                "path": "/",
                "queryString": "",
                "query": {},
                "isDefaultPort": true
            },
            "version": null,
            "revision": "1"
        },
        "operation": {
            "method": "POST",
            "uriTemplate": "/api/Evento/AddEvento/{jsonString}"
        },
        "user": "-",
        "product": "-"
    }
}
cors (0.198 ms)
"Origin header was missing or empty and the request was classified as not cross-domain. CORS policy was not applied."
Backend
(113.817 ms)↑ Back to top
forward-request (0.973 ms)
{
    "message": "Request is being forwarded to the backend service. Timeout set to 300 seconds",
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "https://isitp2.azurewebsites.net/api/Evento/AddEvento/%7B%22id%22:0,%22data%22:%222021-01-20T00:00:00%22,%22dataEvento%22:%222021-01-20T00:00:00%22,%22titulo%22:%22titulo%22,%22descricao%22:%22descricao%22,%22id_utilizador%22:1%7D",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "isitp2.azurewebsites.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Length",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "no-cache, no-store"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept",
                "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                "value": "gzip,deflate,br"
            },
            {
                "name": "Accept-Language",
                "value": "pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
            },
            {
                "name": "Max-Forwards",
                "value": "9"
            },
            {
                "name": "Referer",
                "value": "https://apimanagement.hosting.portal.azure.net/"
            },
            {
                "name": "DNT",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                "value": "61da05a1bfbd4516bbdd72e87f38adce"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
                "value": "cross-site"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
                "value": "cors"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
                "value": "empty"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-For",
                "value": "5.249.23.184,13.91.254.72:1984,13.91.254.72"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL",
                "value": "/api/Evento/AddEvento/%7B%22id%22:0,%22data%22:%222021-01-20T00:00:00%22,%22dataEvento%22:%222021-01-20T00:00:00%22,%22titulo%22:%22titulo%22,%22descricao%22:%22descricao%22,%22id_utilizador%22:1%7D"
            },
            {
                "name": "CLIENT-IP",
                "value": "10.0.32.7:31617"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-ARR-LOG-ID",
                "value": "df8d9a69-47ed-40d4-8428-9ad283d90e16"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID",
                "value": "apimwebappkkpLOUafnze1jpKywpfWHk5GUI9ZrSWiynyTu0DQ"
            },
            {
                "name": "WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME",
                "value": "apimwebappkkplouafnze1jpkywpfwhk5gui9zrswiynytu0dq.azurewebsites.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Original-URL",
                "value": "/api/Evento/AddEvento/{\"id\":0,\"data\":\"2021-01-20T00:00:00\",\"dataEvento\":\"2021-01-20T00:00:00\",\"titulo\":\"titulo\",\"descricao\":\"descricao\",\"id_utilizador\":1}"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-ARR-SSL",
                "value": "2048|256|C=US,O=Microsoft Corporation,CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 02|C=US,S=WA,L=Redmond,O=Microsoft Corporation,CN=*.azure-api.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-Proto",
                "value": "https"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-AppService-Proto",
                "value": "https"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Forwarded-TlsVersion",
                "value": "1.2"
            },
            {
                "name": "DISGUISED-HOST",
                "value": "isitp2-apim.azure-api.net"
            }
        ]
    }
}
forward-request (112.844 ms)
{
    "response": {
        "status": {
            "code": 500,
            "reason": "Internal Server Error"
        },
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Set-Cookie",
                "value": "ARRAffinity=33a9f2010fff78bfe7e62a50798365b8da2f53a72f13afff8a39c13934710a7a;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=isitp2.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=33a9f2010fff78bfe7e62a50798365b8da2f53a72f13afff8a39c13934710a7a;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=isitp2.azurewebsites.net"
            },
            {
                "name": "Server",
                "value": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "X-Powered-By",
                "value": "ASP.NET"
            },
            {
                "name": "Date",
                "value": "Sat, 09 Jan 2021 19:03:32 GMT"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Length",
                "value": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you need something else to solve the problem let me know and i will update this question with the images and code necessary!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your code AddEvent is writing the event to a database.

When it works locally the event is written to the local database.

When you move it to the cloud, it could fail for several reasons:

- The connection string has not been changed, the cloud app cannot reach your local database.
- A database has been created in the cloud, but your app cannot write to it (could be due to many reasons)

The place to start would be to activate application insights, then you would get a detailed error message.

boa sorte

Comment: Locally also writes to the cloud database and it works...

Comment: Are you running it as an app service? Is the app service in a vnet?

Comment: I published the methods to an app service, and my azure api has as endpoint the link for my azure app service

Comment: It could be that you have locked down access to the database, such that it only allows access from your local IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and resolved it by enabling Azure services to access the required resources. Here's what you need to do:

1. **Allow Azure Services Access**: In your database server settings, under networking enable the option to allow Azure services and resources to access the server. This step ensures that your Azure service can communicate with the database.

For visuals refer to this screenshot:

[Allow Azure services and resources to access this server](https://ibb.co/gMP0fp4)

Enabling this setting often resolves the 500 Internal Server Error and enables proper functionality for your Azure API. This is an essential step when transitioning from a local environment to Azure, as connectivity and access permissions are critical.